# increase text input from button

Tags: react-native, textinput, touchableopacity

I am trying to increase/decrease a text input when someone presses a certain button but I am being presented with the following error

[image]

code

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {qty: 1};
  }

<TextInput
                  style={styles.qtyValue}
                  value={this.state.qty}
                  keyboardType='number-pad'
                  defaultValue='1'
                  />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({qty: this.state.qty++})}>
                  <View style={styles.transparentButton}>
                    <Text>+</Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just warning you that you are passing a number into the TextInput and it's expecting value to be a string. You can get rid of it by converting your value to a string when you're passing it as a prop:

```
value={this.state.qty.toString()}
```

Comment: will this effect anything if I need this value for a calculation. also I notice when I click the button the value I have set by default '1' dissappears

Comment: You have to do this.setState({ qty: this.state.qty + 1 }), the way you have it mutates state.